# Combine list from multiple spring-boot YAML files

Tags: spring-boot, flyway, test-data

Is it possible to combine lists of the same elements from multiple spring-boot configuration files written in YAML?

Example:

`postgres.yml` contains my postgres db informations. It also contains the flyway location of my migration scripts:

```
---
flyway:
  locations:
    - flyway/migrations/postgres
```

The same with my oracle migrations:

```
---
flyway:
  locations:
    - flyway/migrations/oracle
```

Now if I want to start my application with test-data, I want to include my `test_data` directory as well (those data work for both postgres and oracle):

```
---
flyway:
  locations:
    - flyway/test_data
```

When I run the application with active profiles `postgres,testdata` the migrations are not loaded, since the locations entry is overridden by the test-data-file.

For this setup I could create four config-files to run each db with and without the test-data, but what would I do, if I have four different databases and three sets of test-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as described in the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge), this isn't currently possible.  If you know the set of profile names ahead of time, you could probably work around this by creating separate lists, prefixed with the profile name, and then in your bean, have in it code that merges them into the final list. That code would just iterate over all known profile name prefixes, and if a profile was not active, that list would be empty.

Unfortunately, this seems harder if you don't own the bean, such as in your Flyway case. It might still be possible though.

Answer (score -1):

Awful hack: what if you created several SpringBoot application contexts by invoking

> SpringApplication.run(MyClass.class)

several times with a different profile each.  Acquire the distinct lists and merge them into one.

Comment: So I adapt my code to my profiles? Nahh... I just moved the test-data to another key abd always provide the full list.